# gigabit ethernet adapter

Tags: speed

I'm having a Toshiba laptop and I'm trying to connect it to gig interface on Cisco 1941 router. my Ethernet adapter on my laptop currently is Realtek FE adapter, I tried to upgrade it realtek GBE adapter but it's still showing FE after installing even though I tried many versions for GBE but with no luck.

I need to make this in order to enable the gig interface to detect 1000 speed.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

You can't "upgrade" hardware by installing another driver. You'll need to buy another NIC for the PC card slot or for USB.